# Which Do I Install First After The OS -- Anti Virus Or Application Software?

Tags: windows-xp

After the installation of the operating system (Windows XP), what advice do you give? Should I install the anti virus first before installing the application software (e.g. MS Office, Adobe, etc.) or vice versa?

Comment: It does not really matter.  Your security software is just another application software which has limited communication capabtilies with the Windows kernel

Comment: XP is out of service now why would you want to be setting a machine up with XP?

Comment: @NathanTaylor Just a friendly note. Not criticizing you. While you are correct, that is not part of the question. XP may be out of service, but it still works. It is not our position to judge their motive. We need to remain open minded to help answer the question. There may be details we don't know; like there may be an application limitation which requires XP.

Comment: @CharlieRB yeah it may have come across that I was criticising but I was trying to understand what the machine is used for. I have experience with software that is not compatible past XP I apologise for coming across that way :)

Comment: @NathanTaylor It is still wayyyy easier to use ;)

Answer (score 4):

You would want to install an antivirus before your other applications, but in general (unless it's an isolated VM) you wouldn't want to set up an XP PC at all.

Answer (score 0):

It is best practice to always install your antivirus before any other application in case of viruses stored on your device (e.g. USB). Plus if you are sourcing your software online you would be better protected against virus attacks if you happen to pick up a malicious site. Its not essential but you will be more secure earlier on in the set up process of your machine.